# How can I get he table fingerprint in database?

Tags: database, fingerprint

I have a problem. How can I get the table fingerprint(like file fingerprint) in database. is there tool for this?

I am looking for solution like forcepoint dlp did.

Comment: What is a "table fingerprint"? Like a hash?

Comment: not hash, like this, https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/data/v84/help/Fingerprinting%20DB.aspx